# Preforming scheduled tasks in C# .NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks, repeat

I'm trying to implement a logic for my .NET MVC application where I would trigger scheduled tasks in my application on a following basis:

```
First scheduled task to run from 00 am to 1 am in the morning
Second scheduled task to run from 1:10 am to 08:00 am in the morning 
Third scheduled task to run from 8:15 am to 11:15 pm every 1 hour
```

This would repeat every day 365 days a year...

Which mechanism in .NET or external library could I use to implement this the easiest way with little code?

I was trying to implement it with Quartz.NET library but I didn't like it at all, I had two scheduled tasks running where one would never run at all for the scheduled time...

Comment: Believe me, you don't want to implement this in your MVC application. If you don't believe me I invite you to read the following blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/

Comment: @DarinDimitrov why not  , can you elaborate it please?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov How would you do it ?

Comment: Sure, read the blog post I have linked to in my comment. And then go ahead and write a Windows Service or a Console Application that will be scheduled to run at the desired intervals with the Windows Scheduler. You absolutely don't want to be implementing recurring background tasks in a web application -> that's one of the worst catastrophes that inexperienced developers do.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Amazing thanks for the clarification! I shall do like that :)

Comment: Hey @DarinDimitrov  should I move the whole logic for the task in the console application or just make the application hit a known point on my website ?

Comment: If it is a long running task, then it's better to offload it to the separate process dedicated for this purpose. You don't need to be wasting the precious threads in your ASP.NET pool which are destined to be serving the standard requests and not doing plumbing.

Comment: So basically I should move the whole logic to the console app/windows service, is that what you're saying, just so that I'm 100% sure I understood you well ? :)

P.S. The tasks are long running, they are performing network requests literally 24/7

Comment: Yeap, that's where this logic should be moved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to be performing long running and recurring background tasks in your web application for multiple reasons. You may go through the [`following blog post`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) which outlines them very well.

I would recommend you moving this logic into a separate Windows Service or even a Console Application whose runs could be scheduled with the Windows Task Scheduler at the desired intervals.

The benefit of this is that you will be off-loading your web application from doing long running tasks which will be consuming precious resources from your webserver. Of course both the webserver and the worker service could share a common centralized datastore or messaging layer in order to communicate if necessary.

Comment: amazing reply ! Not a single line of code, but the information that you've provided is more worth than writing 1000 lines of code! I shall work by this, thanks a lot !!!

Comment: If this is not a long running task you can expose functionality in your web application via web service and then use console application just to call exposed functionality via web service. Console Application can be  scheduled via Windows Scheduler to run on required schedule.

Comment: what about simple task like check database fields or do some job in some dbset at 12:00 am??

Answer (score 6):

For scheduling tasks in ASP.NET MVC you have several options:

- 3rd party libraries like [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler), [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/) or [Quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).
- Since .Net 4.5.2 there is QueueBackgroundWorkItem, a native way to schedule work in the background. [Here is a guide on how to use it with ASP.NET MVC](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2).
- Azure services for background workloads and scheduled tasks. There are a couple of those aimed at different tasks, [here is an overview of them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs).

Be careful if you try to implement a custom solution yourself, as any exception in a thread not associated with a request would halt the entire process.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Cron is a decent task scheduler you can use. We use it, calling service methods on our asp.net / mvc / webapi servers.

http://www.visualcron.com/

Comment: Hi Rick, is this open source or ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways that you can create a scheduled task.

1- Create a WebApi and call it by local console or windows service application in period of time.

2- Using 3rd party libraries like FluentScheduler, HangFire or Quartz.net as Andreas said. it has its own side effects though.

3- If Sql server is used in your application, you can create a procedure for your task and put it on a job in Sql server. you can even use C# for your function if CLR is enabled in Sql Server,

If I want to choose, I will choose Sql Server jobs.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem with my ASP.NET MVC App, I Wanted to do some works in special times and finally I could find a way.
My solution was Plesk scheduels task feature, as where the most windows servers use plesk control panel You can publish your app on a windows server with plesk CP and create a new actionresualt in your MVC App and write Your codes that want to execute them in special times.
By plesk scheduels tasks create a new task and call your Url with a cron that You made it, You can make many crons.
If I Could not explain It very well You can search about Plesk Schedueled Tasks on the Internet, You can find many good answers.

Comment: "As where the most windows server use plesk", no they don't.  Windows Scheduler is on most Windows servers though.