# How to redirect to controller action method from Application_Start() ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect to controller action method from appliction start method in Gloabal.asax.cs. How do i redirect when application start?

I tried :

```
public class SomeStartupClass
{
    public ActionResult Init()
    {

        return new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                {
                    area = "",
                    controller = "InvoiceAddlines",
                    action = "King"
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

And in Global.asx.cs :

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    SomeStartupClass sched = new SomeStartupClass();
    sched.Init();
}
```

So far this is not working, a i will appreciate assistance.

Comment: That makes no sense. You cannot redirect anywhere until a client makes a request.

Comment: So whats your advice?

Comment: What is it your trying to do? (`Application_Start()` is for code which configures your app when its started on the server - it happens before a client can navigate to a method in your app)

Comment: I am trying to email recurring invoices to very client once a month, an email should attach pdf that is generated from view using Rotativa, so far by clicking a button that is linked to action method i am able to email recurring invoices, but now i want it to happen automatically. Application start will call action method, and action method  will check the dates and email invoices.

Comment: The you use a background service (e.g. [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/), but there are many to choose from). Also refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616900/preforming-scheduled-tasks-in-c-sharp-net-mvc-application)