# How to send notifications by email automatically on a date?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a little problem, I don't know how to program a function in .NET MVC to send emails on a date.

For example: Every 25th of each Month send an email to my team partners to remember them update the stock. And the 27th of each Month send and email to his boss to check the stock.

I tried to do this, but i code a function that every time that someone's enter to the WebApp checks the date and if is the 25th sends the email.

**The problems:**

- It sends like thousands of emails, because it is executed every time
  when a person is inside the app.
- If no ones enter to the app the function can be executed :(

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616900/preforming-scheduled-tasks-in-c-sharp-net-mvc-application

Comment: one of the ways to achieve this is to wright a windows service app that will have a timer and every day checks the date and if date equals 25th sends the email, a better approach is to use one of the free schedulers available for .Net. I can suggest  https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ - easy to use and implement

Comment: Take a look at this - [link](https://www.hangfire.io/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a Console application put in a windows server and use the window task scheduler to schedule it.

Answer (score 1):

you could also look at the quartz.net library use that to schedule on a timer

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the Windows Task Scheduler and use it to schedule your e-mail task. The Windows Task Scheduler does not care if your app is running or not.

This could also be a good candidate for an Azure function app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function